# Next.js project Prisma queries not returning expected value from tables based on current user

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma

I've been stuck on this for bit now. I have a Next.js 13 app that you log int to with google sign-in. When you log in you go to a dashboard page. This page returns data from the Linear Api.  The user who logged in has their data stored in a Supabase Postgresql DB.  I am using Next-auth as well in this project.  User data is being stored in the User table and the Session table as well.

I have a table called linearadmins that has user data for the linear accounts. Ive been trying to get a field from the linearadmins table named `linearid` the linearid is what is used to return the correct linear data for the current user.  My code is supposed to use the `Session.userid and the linearadmins.id to return linearadmins.linearid` the code i have now returns the linearid from the first row in the linearadmins table. This is wrong. Currently I have three users in the db. When user 2 or 3 logs in, it does use there google credentials to log in and I can see that, but it still returns data from user 1.
When a user logs in the DB query should take the userid from the session table and find the corresponding id in the linearadmins table and tehn return the linearid.  I dont know why its been so difficult to pull off, it sounds easy in my head.

Here is the code for the db.ts file that does the query, and the linear-api.ts file I have that calls it.

db.ts

```
 import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function getCurrentId(userId: string) {
  const currentId = await prisma.linearadmins.findFirst({
    where: {
      id: userId
    },
    select: {
      linearid: true
    }
  });
  
  return currentId?.linearid;
}

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  if (!session) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Not authenticated' });
    return;
  }

  const currentId = await getCurrentId(session.user.id);
  res.status(200).json(currentId);
}
```

Im sure the query is wrong, but I've tried many iterations and none work, this one at least doesnt break it.  the query i was using in the Supabase query editor is the following:

```
SELECT linearadmins.linearId
FROM linearadmins
JOIN "Session" ON linearadmins.id = "Session".userId
```

here is the linear-api.ts code:

```
import { LinearClient } from "@linear/sdk";

export async function getLinearData(accessToken) {
  const currentIdResponse = await fetch("/api/db");
  const currentId = await currentIdResponse.json();

  const client = new LinearClient({
    accessToken: accessToken,
  });
  
  const user = await client.viewer;  
  const me = await client.user(currentId); 
  const myIssues = await me.assignedIssues();   
  const allIssues = await client.issues({ first: 20 });   
  
  return { user, me, myIssues, allIssues };
}
```

In new to Next and though I know sql Im having issues with this. Im not even sure if this is the correct way of accomplishing this goal but Im not sure what else to try.

schema

```
model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model linearadmins {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  linearid      String?
  status        String?
}
```

Update:  I found that

```
const linearId = await getCurrentId(session.user.id);
```

isnt doing what i thought. its not returning anything because session is referring to the get session data not the session db data. when i console log session. I get the data from google signin. so actually i just changed my code to use session.user.email and i changed the query and now my code works. but I dont think this is proper and would like to figure out how to do it correctly.

Comment: Can you also share the linearadmins and Session models so that I can try to reproduce this locally?